# Grab content from 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want a query to grab results from 2 different tables where a specific user has added the row.  So my 2 tables look like this:

#### addresses

- id
- address
- user_id

#### emails

- id
- email
- user_id

So, I want to pull the content from both tables where the user_id row equals 1. For context, imagine each user can add multiple addresses and emails to the site and I want to grab them all to display on their profile pages.

So I tried this:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM addresses
  JOIN emails USING (user_id) 
 WHERE user_id = '1'
```

However this doesn't work - It either returns 2 of each row from the first table, or nothing at all.
I also tried this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM addresses, 
       emails 
 WHERE user_id = '1'
```

But this also returns nothing.

Comment: Should be an error about an ambiguous column reference because `user_id` exists in both tables.  And the second query is a cartesian product, not a JOIN...  What is the datatype for `user_id`?

Comment: Sorry but isn't that the point of INNER JOINS? To have rows that exist in both tables? How could I join 2 tables on a column if it didn't exist in both tables?

Comment: Also the datatype for user_id is an INT.

Comment: Cartesian product != join - see: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Still a little confused though. Can what I want to do be done with an Inner Join? I feel like the first query makes logical sense. Seems like grabbing from 2 tables where a column equals something specific shouldn't be incredibly difficult.

Comment: @John, when you say the "specific user has added the row", what do you mean by that? To which table was the row added? Were there actually 2 rows added (one to each table)? Also, seeing your PRIMARY and FOREIGN KEYs might be helpful...

Comment: Sorry Branko, should have been more specific. Basically when a user adds a row to a table, their user_id goes into the user_id column. And yes, the user can add a row to either table, and usually they will have added multiple rows to each table through various forms throughout the site. PRIMARY KEYS are the "id" columns.

Comment: @John, so do you want to detect which rows were **newly** added, or do you want to retrieve **all** rows (with given `user_id`)?

Comment: All the rows with the given user_id. Keeping in mind both tables will not have the same amount of rows (ruling out UNIONS, I think).

Comment: @John, then why don't you just use two separate SELECTs?

Comment: Could you provide *useful names* for the tables you're trying to join? perhaps that would make it clearer what you're trying to achieve. Or provide some sample data, and show us the results you'd like to achieve from that sample data.

Comment: @Branko This does work, but in the future I will be updating this query again so it grabs from a couple more tables. I'd rather not have to write 4 separate queries (or however many there may be). The site is (in theory) going to be rather large.

Comment: @Ken Sure, I've updated my original question with more useful names. I don't want to use sample data because I think that would confuse things. But in this example let's say a user can add multiple addresses and emails to the site and I'm trying to grab them all to display on a profile page.

Comment: @John, so this is actually a code maintenance question? Whether you write one big query or X small ones won't make that much of a difference. If anything, maintaining each separate small query ought to be *easier* than fiddling with the large one. The major complexity will be what you do with these rows once they reach your code, not the SQL. BTW, if you are extra worried about performance, ADO.NET has an ability to execute several SQL statements in one database round-trip - perhaps there are similar facilities in PHP (to which I'm not familiar)?

Comment: @Branko Thanks, but here's the thing. In the actual code each row has a time that it was added to the database (time_added), and I want to order the entire list by those times (the most recent stuff added at the top). That's why it's important it all be in one query. I omitted that in my question to keep the basic idea of what I want to do simple. Also I'm not entirely sure if PHP has capabilities like those you mentioned of ADO.NET but nothing I'm familiar with.

Comment: @John: I think I'm still going to need an example of actual data, and what you expect to see in the query. (And if there are duplicate rows, in some way, include that in the example.)

Comment: @Ken Sure. Address table has 3 columns: (id, address, user_id) with 1 row added: (1, 555 Fake Street, 56).  The email table has 3 columns: (id, email, user_id) and 1 row added (1, fake@fake.com, 56). I'd expect the query to return BOTH these rows since they were both added by the user with the user_id 56.

Comment: @John, well then you have two choices: either perform the sort client-side, or make a UNION (see my answer below). Unfortunately the ugliness of that UNION is going to increase with each new table ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Union Version:

```
Select user_id, address as details from addresses
where user_ID = 1
UNION 
Select user_id, email as details from emails
where user_ID = 1
```

Here is some quick reading on union:
http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlunion.php

From Input

```
table1:                        table2

id  user_id  address           id    user_id   email
----------------------         ----------------------
1   1        Add1              1       1       Email1
2   1        Add2              2       1       Email2
3   2        Add3              3       2       Email3
4   2        Add4              4       3       Email4
```

The results will be

```
user_id     details
-----------------------
1           Add1
1           Add2
1           Email1
1           Email2
```

Comment: Returns nothing oddly. Not sure what the "details" part of your code means though?

Comment: MySQL gives me this error: "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Comment: "details" is a column alias, I've added the "as" keyword, I've used that so the columns are the same. Now defiantly 2 columns in each of the queries. Given the other problems encountered so far I'd check the data type of the user_ID column is the same in each of the tables

Comment: Holy cow, this actually works. However, only when I specify all of the columns I want to select (I can't use the *). Any reason for this?

Comment: Yes, the columns between all the queries in the union need to match. Which is why I used the column alias' for email and addresses

Comment: Ah, I understand. Well thanks so much for helping make this work. Thought it was impossible for a while there. And thanks to everyone else who chimed in to help. I know it was a bit messy.

Comment: @John, no problem. And Ken thanks for fleshing out with input & output :-)

Comment: @JonP The problem with this solution is that it is impossible to detect which table the row came from. Also, it becomes impossible to add a table that has "incompatible" type or number of fields. *(Adding a table was indicated as one of the requirements by @John)*

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic, true, though i don't know if it is a requirement to know which table produced the data. This could be over come with a simple modification adding an extra column to the query to store the hard coded table name. As to different data types ,cast should take care of that. Not pretty but it would work.

Comment: Looks totally sick to union email and address columns from different tables, but if thats what @John REALLY wants.. If one would need to be able to differentiate between source tables for rows just add something like 'A' and 'E' into selects like, Select user_id,'A', address as details from addresses

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.*,table2.*
FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
     table2 ON table1.user_ID = table2.user_id
Where table1.user_id = 1
```

From Input

```
table1:                        table2

id  user_id  address           id    user_id   email
----------------------         ----------------------
1   1        Add1              1       1       Email1
2   1        Add2              2       1       Email2
3   2        Add3              3       2       Email3
4   2        Add4              4       3       Email4
```

Expected Output

```
id  user_id address    id      user_id email
----------------------------------------------
1   1       Add1       1       1       Email1
2   1       Add2       1       1       Email1
1   1       Add1       2       1       Email2
2   1       Add2       2       1       Email2
```

Comment: This returns each row from Table1 twice for some reason.

Comment: Is it returning any table 2 information? Is it a one-to-one relationship between table 1 and table 2?

Comment: @John: The table1 duplication is because there's 2+ records in table2 associated the the table1 record.  That is the reality of using a JOIN where a parent has multiple children records associated.

Comment: @JohnP No, not returning any table2 information. And the only thing that each table shares is that the same user could add a multiple rows to each one. Although, the user_id column in each one references a separate 'users' table that contains usernames, etc. So I don't believe it's technically one-to-one.

Comment: @OMGPonies Yes I definitely realize that it is returning duplication of table1 rows because of that. But I can't figure a method to do it that works.

Comment: @Jon, it appears the `user_id` is **not** a key. Therefore, this is going to be a kind of "limited" Cartesian product (i.e. subset_of(table1) X subset_of(table2)).

Comment: Updated the sample to explicitly call all columns from both tables. How many columns are returned and how many do you expect?

Comment: @JonP There are 2 rows in each table right now (each with the same user_id). So I expect it to return all 4 unique rows. It does return 4 rows, but it returns each row from table1 twice and no rows from table2.

Comment: @Jon I would expect 4 rows and 6 columns with this query

Comment: @JonP Yes, 4 rows and 6 columns. But wouldn't you expect those 4 rows to be 4 unique rows (the 2 from each table)? Rather than 4 rows with each row from the first table being displayed twice?

Comment: @JonP Right and it's sort of doing that except it's not even displaying anything from the email table. How would you edit your query so it only displayed each address and each email once?

Comment: @John: I added the input that generates this result. If the input is wrong, you can tell us.

Comment: Dumb question time. Select * from table2 where user_id = 1 does return rows doesn't it?

Comment: @JonP Yes it does. It returns the correct rows. Only becomes a problem when I try to pull from more than one table.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a query using Cartesian Product**

```
SELECT A.*,B.* FROM
(SELECT address FROM addresses WHERE user_id = 1) A,
(SELECT email FROM emails WHERE user_id = 1) B;
```

**Here is a query using INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT A.*,B.* FROM
(SELECT address FROM addresses WHERE user_id = 1) A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT email FROM emails WHERE user_id = 1) B
USING (user_id);
```

Both of these queries are refactored to bring one row each. There is no need to bring the entire dataset together before searching for user_id 1.

One thing to note: Please make user user_id is indexed in both tables:

```
ALTER TABLE addresses ADD INDEX (user_id);
ALTER TABLE emails    ADD INDEX (user_id);
```

Here is something else: If user_id 1 has mutliple addresses and/or multiple emails here is what those two queries should look like:

**Cartesian Product for Multiple Addresses/Multiple Emails**

```
SELECT A.*,B.* FROM
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(address) AddressList FROM addresses WHERE user_id = 1) A,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) EmailList FROM emails WHERE user_id = 1) B;
```

**INNER JOIN for Multiple Addresses/Multiple Emails**

```
SELECT A.*,B.* FROM
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(address) AddressList FROM addresses WHERE user_id = 1) A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) EmailList FROM emails WHERE user_id = 1) B
USING (user_id);
```

Give it a Try !!!

**UPDATE 2011-08-29 11:52 EDT**

Since There is no guarantee a user_id would have both an address and an email address at the same time. You would have to perform a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN since LEFT JOIN would have to favor at least one of those entites existing rather than the INNER JOIN compelling one to have a user_id with both entities. Try one of these:

```
SELECT
    A.ListOfAddresses AddressList,
    IFNULL(B.ListOfEmails,'<No Email Address>') EmailList
FROM
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(address) ListOfAddresses FROM addresses WHERE user_id = 1) A
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) ListOfEmails FROM emails WHERE user_id = 1) B
USING (user_id);
```

or

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(B.ListOfAddresses,'<No Address>') AddressList,
    A.ListOfEmails EmailList
FROM
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) ListOfEmails FROM emails WHERE user_id = 1) A
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(address) ListOfAddresses FROM addresses WHERE user_id = 1) B
USING (user_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately neither of those last 2 return anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING (user_id) WHERE user_id = '1'"
```

then try this one

```
SELECT address.table1 , email.table2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON id.table1 ='1'
```

Comment: Sorry forgot that in my original code (will edit), the 1 is in apostrophes, but it doesn't change the result either way.

Comment: Second query also returns nothing. I'm so baffled by this.

Comment: try this one :)
SELECT address.table1 , email.table2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON id.table1 = id.table2 WHERE id.table1 ='1'

Comment: Unfortunately still returning nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments below the question, the question actually appears to be about sorting rows from different tables based on common criteria.

Beside having separate SELECTs and performing the sort client-side, a database server can perform the sort for you, roughly like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        id addresses_id,
        address address_addresses,
        NULL emails_id,
        NULL emails_email,
        time
    FROM
        addresses
    WHERE
        user_id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        NULL addresses_id,
        NULL address_addresses,
        id emails_id,
        email emails_email,
        time
    FROM
        emails
    WHERE
        user_id = 1
)
ORDER BY
    time -- Column not mentioned in question.
```

NOTE: Some returned rows will have NULLs at the end (these are from the `addresses` table) and some in front (these are from the `emails`).

This UNION is rather ugly and will get uglier with each new table though...

Comment: Aha oddly this code breaks my page (Server Error). Possibly because there is not an equal amount of rows in each table?

Comment: Actually nevermind, it doesn't break the page but it also doesn't return anything.

Comment: @John, please test the SQL independently of PHP, so problems may be isolated more easily. BTW, this query  works on Oracle, but it is pretty standard SQL so I suppose should work on MySQL as well. Whatever the particular syntax, the general idea should be sound...

Comment: right sorry. In mysql I get a "Every derived table must have its own alias" error. Odd will have to look that one up.

Comment: @John, try explicitly specifying column names in the outer SELECT (see the edited answer).

Comment: @John, perhaps just add an alias after `FROM (SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ...)`?